# Solr - Get the sum of all "filemetadata.filesize" field for a given user

Tags: solr

I'm building some kind of file storage software.
The files metadata are indexed with fields like `filesize` and `userId`
The

What I'd like to do is to be able to compute the space used by an user.

For exemple if I have documents:

- documentId = 1 | userId = 1 | fileSize = 10
- documentId = 2 | userId = 2 | fileSize = 5
- documentId = 3 | userId = 1 | fileSize = 3

I'd like to run a query so that for userId=1 I retrieve a result being 13MB (10+3)

---

I have seen that we can run [FunctionQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Same for the [FieldCollapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) which doesn't permit to run aggregation functions on the grouped results.

---

I have tested the StatsComponent as well but it doesn't seem to work for unknown reasons.

My schema contains:

```
<field name="FileSize" type="integer" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="OtherField" type="sfloat" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
<field name="OtherField2" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="OtherField3" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
```

And when I perform the query

```
http://mysolr:8414/solr/mycore/select/?q=docId:123
&rows=0
&stats=true
&stats.field=FileSize
&stats.field=OtherField
&stats.field=OtherField2
&stats.field=OtherField3
```

I get back the result:

```
<lst name="stats">
  <lst name="stats_fields">
    <null name="FileSize"/>
    <lst name="OtherField">
      <double name="min">6.0</double>
      <double name="max">6.0</double>
      <long name="count">1</long>
      <long name="missing">0</long>
      <double name="sum">6.0</double>
      <double name="sumOfSquares">36.0</double>
      <double name="mean">6.0</double>
      <double name="stddev">0.0</double>
      <lst name="facets"/>
    </lst>
    <lst name="OtherField2">
      <double name="min">0.0</double>
      <double name="max">0.0</double>
      <long name="count">1</long>
      <long name="missing">0</long>
      <double name="sum">0.0</double>
      <double name="sumOfSquares">0.0</double>
      <double name="mean">0.0</double>
      <double name="stddev">0.0</double>
      <lst name="facets"/>
    </lst>
    <null name="OtherField3"/>
  </lst>
</lst>
```

As you can see I'm asking for stats for a single doc (which isn't really useful but helps to debug, anyway without the `q=docId:123` it doesn't return me a better result).
This document has a set FileSize of 15
I use Solr 4.1

Can someone please explain me why I can get stats for fields `OtherField` and `OtherField2`, but not for fields `FileSize` and `OtherField3`? I don't see the problem at all...

Comment: Re StatsComponent - why do you have q=docId:123? Shouldn't it be q=userId:1 instead?

Comment: In my final query yes, but to help debug I filtred on docId directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, writing this question helped me find the solution. I use a legacy schema and didn't notice that the `FileSize` field had `indexed="false"`.
Passing this attribute to true makes the StatsComponent returns stats for that field!

However, for the field `OtherField3` which has exactly the same definition as `OtherField2`, I have no answer